# Virtual move constructor in C++

Tags: c++, move-semantics

Just faced with a situation and don't know what to do... Here is the code I have right now:

```
class IMyDbAccessor {
 public:
  int getSum();  // quite important for my case that it is not const.
                 // it does some caching. Of course I may use mutable,
                 // but actually it is not that important here.
};

void SomeBusinessLogic(IMyDbAccessor& dbacc) { /* implementation */ }

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    MyDbAccessor acc(argv);
    SomeBusinessLogic(acc);
}
```

I don't like it, because it is not expressive enough. I would like to have

```
void SomeBusinessLogic(IMyDbAccessor&& dbacc) { /* implementation */ }
```

to show that `SomeBusinessLogic` wants to own a passed object, so `main` should look like

```
int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    MyDbAccessor acc(argv);
    SomeBusinessLogic(std::move(acc));
}
```

But of course it is impossible... Does anyone know what was a reasoning for that? For me it makes a perfect sense.

Or my feelings are wrong and I should not make `SomeBusinessLogic` responsible for `IMyDbAccessor` ownership, so it's better to pass it as a `const IMyDbAccessor&`?

Comment: Any reason you can't use an owning handle, like `std::unique_ptr`? That one you can move.

Comment: By the way, I think you are confused about what ownership is. In your example the ownership of `acc` is scoped anyway. The fact it is modified in a function doesn't give it ownership of it. Not unless it attempts to free it.

Comment: Thank you @StoryTeller ! You advise for `unique_ptr` is probably a solution. In general I understand that there is nothing wrong in passing non-constant object to a function. It's more about the agreements that we have. Probably to make reasoning about multithreading easier... But `unique_ptr` looks... Well, like a good workaround :) Thanks!

Comment: I would keep it as it is. Is there really a good reason why `SomeBusinessLogic` should own the `MyDbAccessor` instead of just use it? Maybe later you want to add `if(special_case) SomeAdditionalLogic(acc);`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> I don't like it, because it is not expressive enough.

Looks plenty expressive to me.  Passing an object by reference means the function can operate on an existing object provided by the caller, not on a copy.  No worries about managing ownership.

> I would like to have
>
> ```
> void SomeBusinessLogic(IMyDbAccessor&& dbacc) { /* implementation */ }
> ```
>
> to show that `SomeBusinessLogic` wants to own a passed object

That is not what an rvalue reference represents.  An rvalue reference means that `dbacc` will refer to either a *temporary* object created by the compiler at the actual call site, or a pre-existing object that the caller passes with `std::move()`.  Either way, the object that `dbacc` refers to is expected not to be used anymore after `SomeBusinessLogic()` exits, so `SomeBuinessLogic()` is allowed to "steal" ownership of any *internal data* held by the object that `dbacc` refers to, instead of make copies of it.  This has nothing to do with ownership of the object itself.  That still lies strictly with the caller.

> so `main` should look like
>
> ```
> int main(int argc, char** argv) {
>     MyDbAccessor acc(argv);
>     SomeBusinessLogic(std::move(acc));
> }
> ```
>
> But of course it is impossible...

What you are looking for is `std::unique_ptr`:

```
void SomeBusinessLogic(std:::unique_ptr<IMyDbAccessor> dbacc) { /* implementation */ }

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    std::unique_ptr<IMyDbAccessor> acc(new MyDbAccessor(argv));
    SomeBusinessLogic(std::move(acc));
}
```

Or:

```
int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    SomeBusinessLogic(std::make_unique<MyDbAccessor>(argv));
}
```

Only one `std::unique_ptr` at a time should ever hold a given pointer, as `std::unique_ptr` frees the memory being pointed at when destructed.  That is what makes it "unique".  When you see a `std::unique_ptr`, you *know* who the owner is.  And passing a `std::unique_ptr` object by value to a function means it exists only for the lifetime of the function.

So, this approach makes it *very* clear that `dbacc` itself, not the caller, holds exclusive ownership of the `IMyDbAccessor` object, and will free that object when `SomeBusinessLogic()` exits (unless `SomeBusinessLogic()` decides to `std::move()` `dbacc` to another `std::unique_ptr` that is outside of `SomeBusinessLogic()`).

> Or my feelings are wrong and I should not make `SomeBusinessLogic` responsible for `IMyDbAccessor` ownership, so it's better to pass it as a `const IMyDbAccessor&`?

I would, yes.  Unless there is some compelling reason that `SomeBusinessLogic()` must take ownership away from the caller.

Comment: Thank you! That helped a lot. I think my main confusion comes from our codebase, that is quite simple in general, and most of the objects are constructed once as a const objects and then passed as a const references. So it looks more like a functional programming in C++ . And now this object, with a state, that can be change by any other function, who have a reference to it. I'm scared! But it looks from the replies here, that it is acceptable for other developers...

Answer (score 4):

I think the type you are looking for is probably `void SomeBusinessLogic(std::unique_ptr<IMyDbAccessor>)`?

Indicates ownership is being transferred, and accepts derived objects

Comment: Did you mean `void SomeBusinessLogic(std::unique_ptr<IMyDbAccessor>&&)`?

Comment: No, it is expected that `std::unique_ptr` be passed by value, not by reference. See my answer.  It makes no sense to pass a `std::unique_ptr` using an rvalue reference.

Answer (score 0):

Do SomeBusinessLogic(std::forward(acc)).

For example:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <utility>

class IMyDbAccessor {
public:
  virtual int getSum() = 0;

};

class MyDbAccessor : public IMyDbAccessor {
public:
    virtual int getSum() { return 0; }

};

void SomeBusinessLogic(IMyDbAccessor&& dbacc) { std::cout << dbacc.getSum() << std::endl; }

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    MyDbAccessor acc;
    SomeBusinessLogic(std::forward<MyDbAccessor>(acc));
}
```

Try it here: 
http://cpp.sh/7pbrm

Comment: why not `SomeBusinessLogic(MyDbAccessor{});`?

Comment: Maybe he wants to do something like acc.setSum() before he calls SomeBusinessLogic ()? Dunno. What I got from his request was that SomeBusinessLogic() should get MyDbAccessor as of it was a temporary object.

Comment: If I get you right, `SomeBusinessLogic(MyDbAccessor{});` is exactly what I want to have, but it is impossible because move-constructor is not virtual.

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking for a way to give feedback "Hey I will modify this variable!" at the call location, I strongly recommend const pointers.

Then you have:

```
void SomeBusinessLogic(IMyDbAccessor* const dbacc) { /* implementation */ }
```

and

```
int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    MyDbAccessor acc;
    SomeBusinessLogic(&acc);
}
```